# hover over li to change color in twitter bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to make the inner text turn green when I hover over. However it is not doing so and I am not sure why. I am using Twitter bootstrap

[image]

Here is my code:

CSS:

```
#nav_pills li:hover {
    color: green;
}
```

HTML:

```
  <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
    <ul id="nav_pills" class="nav nav-pills" role="tablist">
      <li role="presentation"><a href="#about">About</a></li>
      <li role="presentation"><a href="#services">Services</a></li>
      <li role="presentation"><a href="#portfolio">Portfolio</a></li>
      <li role="presentation"><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Add the `a`selector to your CSS

```
#nav_pills li:hover a{
   color: green;
}
```

Comment: You apply a selector to the a tag, because you want to change the color of the link (`<a>`) which contains your text/value

Answer (score 3):

replace

```
    #nav_pills li:hover a {
    color: green;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply change it to

```
#nav_pills li:hover a{
   color: green;
}
```

Here's a little [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tycfkuqq/) for you